# how to generate human readable intermidiat code by llvm

Tags: clang-static-analyzer, llvm-clang

I want to use clang to print out the abstract syntax tree in a human readable, do not want the binary bytecode one.

I have used:

1. ast-print
2. ast-dump

but they are providing non-readable code..

Could some one help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to invoke the cc1 to get the output in desired format.

This should help:

```
clang++ -cc1 test.cpp -ast-dump
```

Otherwise if you want machine level instructions then try:

```
clang++ test.cpp -mllvm -print-after-all
```